# ¿Por qué no funciona el código de mi función onMouseEnter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pese a que aquí parece funcionar no lo hace en Dreamweaver, Chrome ni Safari. No logro entender qué es lo que está mal. Gracias.

```js
$("#hoverDiv").mouseenter(function() { $("#hiddenDiv").css('display','block'); });
```

```css
#hiddenDiv{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hoverDiv">hover on me</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv">show/hide div</div>
```

Comment: Acá me funciona https://jsfiddle.net/nkjfs9xk/ probado con Chrome Versión 49.0.2623.87 m. La verdad no entiendo tu problema. Adicionalmente es aconsejable el uso de la ultima versión de jquery, ya que esas que usas quedo obsoleta hace un tipo atrás, la actual es 2.2.1

Comment: @WilfredoP yo tampoco lo entiendo pero en mi ordenador no funciona... no sé cómo resolver este problema. Ya actualicé la versión.

Comment: Haz tratado de borrar cache??? probar en otro navegador???? mirar si tienes erres en la consola????

Comment: @WilfredoP lo solucione así:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hoverDiv").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#hiddenDiv").fadeIn(0);
  });
});

Answer (score 3):

Había olvidado colocar lo siguiente: `$(document).ready(function(){`
Lo resolví así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hoverDiv").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#hiddenDiv").fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Deberías incluir una descripción de por qué el nuevo código sí funciona y el anterior no. Es un fallo bastante simple, pero que se ve a menudo y podría ser de utilidad para otros usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el evento `hover` en vez de `mouseenter`:

```
$("#hoverDiv").hover(function() { $("#hiddenDiv").css('display','block'); });

#hiddenDiv{display:none;}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hoverDiv">hover on me</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv">show/hide div</div>
```

Comment: Tampoco funciona y no estoy seguro de que cumpla la función que quiero, ya que necesito que se muestre el div de forma permanente y no solo mientras el puntero está sobre éle.

Comment: Si va a cumplir la función. Porque NO es el hover de css, es un evento jquery, cuando se ejecute el hiddenDiv va a quedar con el atributo display=block

Comment: Sería bueno indicar una explicación de por qué esto resolvería el problema y cuáles pueden haber sido las causas del problema que OP experimentó.

Comment: Difícil saber cuales pueden haber sido las causas del problema, ya que el código que puso en la pregunta funciona bien. Yo le di una alternativa que también funciona.

Comment: Entonces sería bueno si colocas "Tu código funciona bien. Quizás puedes intentar esto". La forma como está redactada ahora luce a que él se equivocó (sin saber por qué) y que tu propuesta mágicamente (porque no provees ninguna explicación adicional) va a resolver sus problemas al 100%.

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo que mala política la tuya de ponerse a votar en contra de mis publicaciones solo porque te pido mejorar una de las tuyas. Pero bueno, son solo puntos de unicornio ;)